# SQL Query Needed ( based on the column value, row value should be loaded )

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

My Sql query is,

```
Select CustomerName,ProjectID,ProjectDesc from dbo.projects

The Output is:

CustomerName                     ProjectID   ProjectDesc
```

---

```
A3 Consulting FZ, LLC.          277         A3
A3 Consulting FZ, LLC.          278         A3 - Chef
Anesthesia Business Consultant  279         Astra
ARI Network Services, Inc.      280         Mira
```

**What i want is,the project desc should be in row as per the customer.**

```
CustomerName               ProjectDesc     ProjectID
```

---

```
A3 Consulting FZ, LLC.                   

                                A3            277    
                                A3 - Chef     278    

Anesthesia Business Consultant  

                                Astra         279

ARI Network Services, Inc.

                                Mira          280
```

Comment: This is a presentation layer issue, not database...

Comment: Then perhaps SQL is not what you want.

Comment: I agree this is presentation issue, not SQL's fault

Comment: No i want the sql query should return the value like this.

Comment: @RobinHood: it can't be done in SQL. That's why everyone says "presentation". Voting to close

Comment: It can't be exactly done in SQL, but the query below gets pretty close.   But I agree, this should be done in the presentation side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments, this is not a Query issue, but a display issue.   But if you really want to do it in SQL, try this.

```
Select a.CustomerName,'' as ProjectDesc,'' as ProjectID,
       a.CustomerName+'1' as SortKey
from dbo.projects a
join dbo.projects b on b.CustomerName=a.customerName
union 
Select '' ,b.ProjectDesc,cast(b.ProjectID as varchar(20)),
       a.customerName+'99'
from dbo.projects a
join dbo.projects b on b.CustomerName=a.customerName
order by 4
```

It will give you what you want, but it has an extra sort key column on the end that your front end will need to get rid of...

Here is another approach if you want to hide that key

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SortKey) as RowNum,
       CustomerName, ProjectDesc, ProjectID
from
(
Select a.CustomerName,'' as ProjectDesc,'' as ProjectID ,
       a.CustomerName+'1' as SortKey
from dbo.projects a
join dbo.projects b on b.CustomerName=a.customerName
where departmentID = @DeptID
union 
Select '' ,b.ProjectDesc,cast(b.ProjectID as varchar(20)),
       a.customerName+'99'
from dbo.projects a
join dbo.projects b on b.CustomerName=a.customerName
where departmentID = @DeptID
) xx
order by 1
```

This approach will convert the ugly key into a series of sequential numbers.   But just because this CAN be done in SQL, doesn't mean it SHOULD be...

Comment: Hi just amazing..Exactly what i want is here ( 1 solution )..Thanks a lot...A small request, in the same table i am having departmentID column..i will pass the departmentID as parameter, so based on that the output should come..

Comment: See the modification to the second query example...

Comment: select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SortKey) as RowNum,
       CustomerName, ProjectDesc, ProjectID, DepartmentID,
from
(
Select a.CustomerName,'' as ProjectDesc,'' as ProjectID, '' as DepartmentID,
       a.CustomerName+'1' as SortKey
from dbo.projects a
join dbo.projects b on b.CustomerName=a.customerName
where a.DepartmentID = '52'
union 
Select '' ,b.ProjectDesc,cast(b.ProjectID as varchar(20)),cast(b.DepartmentID as varchar(20)),
       a.customerName+'99'
from dbo.projects a
join dbo.projects b on b.CustomerName=a.customerName
where b.DepartmentID = '52'
) xx
order by 1

Comment: i had changed the query like this..but its showing error..

Comment: What is the error?  In the code above, you do have an extra comma after the department ID and before the FROM

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near 'xx'.

Comment: DepartmentID, from    (Remove the comma after departmentID)

Comment: OMG..Once again Thanks a lot Sparky...its working good...

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in sql server 2005. I think this will defiantly work...

```
   create table #projects1 
    (
    CustomerName varchar(max),
    ProjectDesc varchar(max),
    ProjectID varchar(max)
    );


declare @count int;
declare @lastname varchar(max),@CustomerName varchar(max),@ProjectID varchar(max),@ProjectDesc varchar(max);
set @count=0;
set @lastname='';
declare pro_cursor CURSOR for
select CustomerName, ProjectDesc, ProjectID from projects
open pro_cursor
fetch next from pro_cursor into @CustomerName,@ProjectDesc,@ProjectID
    while(@@fetch_status=0)
    begin
        if(@lastname!=@CustomerName)
        begin
            if(@count=0)
            begin
                set @lastname=@CustomerName;
                set @count=@count+1;
            end         
            set @lastname=@CustomerName;
            insert into #projects1 values (@CustomerName,'','');
            insert into #projects1 values ('',@ProjectDesc,@ProjectID);
        end     
        else
        begin
            insert into #projects1 values ('',@ProjectDesc,@ProjectID)
        end
    fetch next from pro_cursor into @CustomerName,@ProjectDesc,@ProjectID
    end
select * from #projects1
close pro_cursor;
deallocate pro_cursor
truncate table #projects1
```